# Realsense D435 change resolution in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, realsense

I see that the example python code from Intel offers a way to change the resolution as below:

```
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.depth, 640, 480, rs.format.z16, 30)
# Start streaming
pipeline.start(config)
```

https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/wrappers/python/examples/opencv_viewer_example.py

I am trying to do the same thing in MATLAB as below, but get an error:

```
config = realsense.config();
config.enable_stream(realsense.stream.depth,1280, 720, realsense.format.z16, 30);

pipeline = realsense.pipeline();

% Start streaming on an arbitrary camera with default settings
profile = pipeline.start(config);
```

Error is below:

```
Error using librealsense_mex
Couldn't resolve requests

Error in realsense.pipeline/start (line 31)
                    out = realsense.librealsense_mex('rs2::pipeline',
                    'start', this.objectHandle, varargin{1}.objectHandle);

Error in pointcloudRecordCfg (line 15)
profile = pipeline.start(config);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Using this to print realsense available for available configuration profile

code snippet from
https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/blob/master/examples/python/reconstruction_system/sensors/realsense_helper.py

pyrealsense2 is required.
Please see instructions in https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/master/wrappers/python

````
import pyrealsense2 as rs

def get_profiles():
    ctx = rs.context()
    devices = ctx.query_devices()
    color_profiles = []
    depth_profiles = []

    for device in devices:
        name = device.get_info(rs.camera_info.name)
        serial = device.get_info(rs.camera_info.serial_number)
        print('Sensor: {}, {}'.format(name, serial))
        print('Supported video formats:')
        for sensor in device.query_sensors():
            for stream_profile in sensor.get_stream_profiles():
                stream_type = str(stream_profile.stream_type())

                if stream_type in ['stream.color', 'stream.depth']:
                    v_profile = stream_profile.as_video_stream_profile()
                    fmt = stream_profile.format()
                    w, h = v_profile.width(), v_profile.height()
                    fps = v_profile.fps()

                    video_type = stream_type.split('.')[-1]
                    print('  {}: width={}, height={}, fps={}, fmt={}'.format(
                        video_type, w, h, fps, fmt))
                    if video_type == 'color':
                        color_profiles.append((w, h, fps, fmt))
                    else:
                        depth_profiles.append((w, h, fps, fmt))

    return color_profiles, depth_profiles```
````

Answer (score 0):

I use this and it works.

```
config = realsense.config();
config.enable_stream(realsense.stream.depth,640,480,realsense.format.z16,30);
config.enable_stream(realsense.stream.color,640,480,realsense.format.rgb8,30);
% Make Pipeline object to manage streaming
pipe = realsense.pipeline();
% Start streaming with default settings
profile = pipe.start(config);
```